# c - const pointer to const data (gcc - duplicate 'const' declaration specifier)

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I am programming a module on a microcontoller for interfacing it's EEPROM to receive some user data from there. Since you can not overwrite the EEPROM easily I want to return a `const` pointer to `const` data.

Now my functions prototype looks like this:

`const struct userData const* getEEPROMDataAtIndex(uint32_t uidIndex)`

while gcc tells me `duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]`. Shouldn't each const I use have a different effect? One to make the pointed-to data immutable, the other for the received pointer not to be retarged?

Comment: When I use `const struct userData *const getEEPROMDataAtIndex(uint32_t uidIndex)` I get `type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]` as a warning. In the output the `^~~~~`-arrow points to the first const, so it would be only a cont pointer now with the data behind it not, right?

Comment: There are no const rvalues in C ;  consequently. `int const foo(void);` is the same as `int foo(void);`. This doesn't change if you replace `int` by `const struct userdata *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seems have some miss understanding about const, for example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=123, b=456;
    const int *pa = &a;
    pa = &b;    //legal 
    *pa = 4;    //illegal
    printf("a=%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

gcc will give an error saying that

```
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:8:9: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*pa’
     *pa = 4;
         ^
```

for your purpose, if I understand correctly, you should define the function as

```
const struct userData * getEEPROMDataAtIndex(uint32_t uidIndex);
//this const declare the returned pointer point to something cannot be changed
```

then when you initiate your constant pointer by call this function

```
const struct userData * const myp = getEEPROMDataAtIndex(index);
//                       ^ this declare the pointer itself (myp) cannot be changed
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, got the point. Thanks a lot! But for me effectivly this means, that the caller is responsible for making the pointer const, which I wanted to do by the return type of the function automatically... This means i can not secure that a returned pointer is const pointing to constant data on an interface level (return type)?

Comment: you returned a value (pointer) to outside world of that function, and it is assigned to a 2nd variable (another pointer), I don't think you can control the 2nd variable if it's modifiable, it is out of the scope.

Comment: @PaulWürtz I don't see how it would be useful to demand that the assigned-to pointer be constant. The structure pointed to is still constant and you would have to do some sketchy pointer casting if you wanted to modify the structure. Woo hoo I'm now allowed to comment, thanks a lot.

Comment: I feel like need to add that the function declare to return the const pointer is informative, not mandatory, how to use that pointer is upto the caller.

Answer (score 5):

You have declared your struct const twice. Since it doesn't make sense to make the pointer const in a return type, just remove one of the const declarations. If you wanted to make the pointer const (which doesn't really make sense in a return type) you would put const after the asterisk.

Answer (score -2):

`const struct userData const*` => `const struct userData *const`

It can be used during the initilalisation of the automatic variable:

```
const struct userData * const foo(void);

void bar(void)
{
    const struct userData *const ptr_to_something = foo();

    /* some code */ 
}
```

Comment: There is a strange non printable character after the '=' in your answer , and may be your answer is too 'dry' ? (I did not DV ^^)

Comment: I do not know about the vote down, but what do you think `const struct userData *const` does when the OP is declaring a function? Functions return values. `const` affects only lvalues—it says an object will not change. E.g., if you have `const int x = 4;`, that means `x` will not change. But a function just returns a value, like 4. A value is just a value, not an object that can change. So `const` has no effect on it. Per C 2018 6.7.3 5, “The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that are lvalues.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil `const struct userData *const foo();` try cdecl.org and see my answer again

Comment: Interesting delete vote. Any explanation? Revenge or a bad day?

Comment: OP’s question asks about declaring a function. The declaration of an object is not relevant. cdecl.org is irrelevant; there is no dispute that the type is nominally const-qualified. It is just that the qualifier is meaningless for a function declaration.

Comment: Declaration of the function : `const struct userData * const foo(void);`

Comment: What is your godbolt.org example supposed to prove?

Answer (score -3):

I suggest using `typdef` to type define your return data type. Then in the function declaration you only need to declare the return type as the typedef name.

For example...

```
typedef struct USER_DATA
{
....
...
};
```

I think it would simplify things a bit.
what happens if you interchange '`const struct`' ... to '`struct const`'?

Comment: Change to `struct const uid_t *const getPersisitedUIDAtIndex(uint32_t uidIndex);` doesn't compile giving `expected '{' before 'const'`. I agree on using a `typedef` later, but omiting it here for simplicity.

Comment: `typedef`ing is unrelated to this question, so it just adds nothing to it.